# how many initial conditions are needed for a specific solution to a non-linear, autonomous second order differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

i am trying to find the coefficients to a general solution for non-linear, autonomous second order ordinary differential equation, i have ended up with a general solution that has 4 integration constants. does this mean that i need 4 initial conditions? and if so which? i know that i can already use the initial condition for the function itself and the first derivative, but i don't know what else i could use.
the function in question is:

$$|x|={e}^ {\frac {\pm2k \left(\mathtt{erfi}^{-1} \left(\frac{e^{{2kC_3+C_1 \over 2k}}\sqrt{2k}\left(C_2-C_4\pm t \right)} {\sqrt{\pi}} \right)^2 \right)-C_1} {2k}} $$

[here is a picture of the function in desmos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqMuA.png)

$\mathtt{erfi}^{-1}$ is the inverse imaginery error function, hopefully the function is readable.
also the initial conditions i think i already have are $x(0) = R_0$ and $x'(0)=0$.
the initial equation that was solved was:
$$x''(t)={k \over x(t)}. $$
where k is a predefined constant. and the integration constants that are unknown are $C_1,C_2,C_3$ and $C_4$, here it should likely be noted that $C_1$ and $C_2$ where already there because of the solution method i used, which was looking op a solution and then solving using that solution:[this is that solution](https://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0301.pdf), and the other two were a result of the integration in the solution.

Comment: Generally, whether ODEs or linear equations, you need as many equations/initial conditions as you have unknowns. On the other hand, you only need as many unknowns as the order of the ODE you are working with. Can you show your work to give more details?

Comment: do you mean my work or my end result

Comment: The solution of a second order ODE has two indeterminate parameters. It is likely that your four constants are not independent, or some are known.

An autonomous ODE yields a time-invariant solution, $f(t-t_0)$, so this must be one of the independent constants.

Comment: sorry could you explain that @YvesDaoust. im a bit new to differential equations

Comment: The constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ in the last link represent the integration constants of the two integrals. You do not have to add new constants.

Comment: @Gonçalo i believe that this isnt the case and that they are a result of the derivation of solution in the link.

Comment: Compare your solution with $C_3=C_4=0$ with the solution of [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27%28t%29%3Dk%2Fx).

Comment: @Erginarity: what don't you understand ?